# Does pd.Period max out at microsecond period?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to see just how detailed I can make a `pd.Period` and here's what I got:

```
pd.Period('2016-01-01 10:10:10.123456789')
```

which produces:

```
Period('2016-01-01 10:10:10.123456', 'U')
```

Is that really the max? I didn't see this addressed in the docs, but perhaps I'm missing it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nanosecond, which is finer than microsecond (U):

```
In [11]: pd.Period("2016-01-01", "n")
Out[11]: Period('2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000000', 'N')

In [12]: pd.Period("2016-01-01", "u")
Out[12]: Period('2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'U')
```

The possible frequencies are in the [dateoffset list](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).

Comment: The string representation doesn't appear to be explicitly enumerated, the < daily ones are listed in the Period docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#period

Comment: It's still not clear why Pandas truncates the information beyond microseconds, though. `pd.Period('2016-01-01 10:10:10.123456789', 'n')` gives `Period('2016-01-01 10:10:10.123456000', 'N')`, for example.

Comment: @MarkDickinson that looks like a bug in the constructor. You can get a nanosecond period as follows: `pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01 10:10:10.123456789']).to_period('n')`

Comment: @MarkDickinson but not `pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01 10:10:10.123456789').to_period('n')`. Definitely a bug!

Comment: @AndyHayden  Thanks much for this spirited discussion. Will one of you file the bug? If not I will do it.